# UIScrollView zoom in bounce

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, pinchzoom

I have embedded an image view into a scroll view for zooming purposes. Everything works great but if the user choses to zoom in then pan in any direction the user can slightly pull the `ScrollView` off the screen bounds exposing the content i have behind the `scrollview` before bouncing back. I want to disable this bouncing when zoomed in but don't know how. This only happens when zoomed in. At normal zoom scale you can't do it. Heres my code I have gone through the [UIScrollView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bouncesZoom) and have commented out my attempts at disabling it but it doesn't work!

```
    zoomScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(enlargedPhotoImageView.frame.size.width , enlargedPhotoImageView.frame.size.height);
    zoomScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10;
    zoomScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
    zoomScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    zoomScrollView.delegate = self;
    zoomScrollView.zoomScale = 1;
    //zoomScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
    //zoomScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
    //zoomScrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if(scrollView == zoomScrollView){
        return enlargedPhotoImageView;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
zoomScrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Will prevent overscroll. But...scrollviews that don't bounce usually feel very weird to users; bear in mind that there's probably a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: like what? You mean for zooming in on an image? I don't think it'll be weird as this scrollviews only purpose is to contain this image

Comment: @NewbyScoobyDoo I mean, try it and see what you think. People are so used to the overscroll effect that when something pans and *doesn't* bounce, it just feels...weird and broken. But I'm generalizing. I don't know the specifics of your use case; if what you're doing feels good then run with it.

Comment: Thank you your answer worked not sure why but I had bouncing unchecked in interface builder had to programmatically do it too?